# Arrange fields in a view

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

Now after searching for 2 weeks afther a module to work on drupal 7.x version whatever, I took another way/module/guide/tutorial and yes finally i got somehow what i want without a error occures.

But now i want to make something very simple but i don't see it.

I have the module view and panel. And i want to list 3 fields in the next way:

**so you need 10 reputation for images, i'll try it to explain it like this:

|=

(where "|" is the thumbnail and "-" are the title and the other "-" is the date.

Now it shows like this:

title
date
thumbnail

I see alot on the internet about , display suite, panels, view with rewrite output, ...

But this must be soooo simple and that is getting me crazy. If i know how i just could write it myself in php/html whatever i would do it.

But i can't see the forest for the trees

Please give me something to work with or a link of a tutorial whatever. I need a right direction for this.

Yes my english is bad and i hate drupal, but still , i think drupal can be great, but it is not for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about "theming" which is how your fields are displayed on the screen. By default Views emits some HTML that wraps them in elements like . The exact HTML depends on which type of display you are using.

The quickest way to achieve the layout you describe is not really about Views at all, but using CSS.  Make the thumbnail float:left and ensure the other two are displayed inline (without line break).

Comment: Thanks for the direction, i found CSS injector module, works like a charm !